# jqGrid: double clicking a row twice needs to be disabled

Tags: jqgrid, jquery

I have a jqgrid named: grid2.
When I click on a row it starts editing it and adds some small editing icons aside.
But if I double click once again (or hundreds again) in that editing input, it appends over and over the icons causing a mess.

```
ondblClickRow: function(id){
$("#grid2").editRow(id);
displayEditIcons('grid2', id, 'id');
},
```

I need either to suprime the twice double clicking event or remove the dbclick event handler for the input.

One clue would be to add this line inside jqGrid event:

```
$("#grid2 input").bind('dblclick',function(e){$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');});
```

but I need: 1. not to disable the input but the handler 2. It only works on the third click. 3. It should be working on all active row fields.

**ps. I found the fix** I found the fix in case someone is interested.

```
$("#grid2 input").bind('dblclick',function(e){ return false; });
```

Comment: You can define a javascript variable, say `isEditClicked`, which is by default `false` but set to `true` when the edit is clicked

Comment: I have no idea how to do that in the ondblClickRow context

Comment: I found the fix in case someone is interested.
$("#grid2 input").bind('dblclick',function(e){ return false; });

Comment: You should post this as an answer, so everyone on SO knows this question is done...